# Can I integrate React into a Knockout JavaScript app?

Tags: javascript, c#, reactjs, mvvm, knockout.js

I've been building an application in my spare time, its backend is C# and I use Knockout js for the front end, to be honest its an app I use out side of my main job for learning purposes etc, I may launch it one day not really sure. I've now a new job where they use React, so my question is can I now integrate React into my app so I can begin learning this library? I'd aim to keep each component separate but does anyone think this a bad idea mixing libraries like this? I haven't learnt React yet hence I want to start integrating it into my side project though I don't really want to start rewriting all the Knockout JavaScript again also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A React app can be initialized on any DOM node you want. Pick a page you want to put React on, create a DOM node (a simple `div`) and create a Element on that node.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
    <title>Hello World</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">
      function App() {
        return <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
      }
      
      ReactDOM.render(
        <App />,
        document.getElementById('root')
      );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```